# How to add same prefix to all LOGS in request in SpringBoot project

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

I use @Slf4j to add logs in all layers in my SpringBoot project.
I want to use some unque ID for all logs inside onq request.
For example generate UUID at the RestController and automatic add it to every logs in this thread
For example

```
[..... Some UUID ....] "The real logger message"
```

How to do this?
It need to have possibility to filter all logs of specific request.

Comment: What you’re looking for is called tracing. Google “Spring Sleuth”.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is threaded (or any better word to describe "opposed to a reactive application where it might be possible that everything happens in the main thread"), use the mapped diagnostic context (MDC). The MDC is a thread-bound Key-Value Map, where you can put and retrieve data. Baeldung has a [tutorial on logging with the mdc](https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback) using multiple logging frameworks. Also, there are plenty of examples across the web.
If your application should be reactive, you may wanna check out [this project reactor reference.](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.mdc)